# Unable to install Apache in Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: apache2

Before I install Apache2 in Ubuntu 16.04 execute command `sudo apt-get update` but there is error (please see below):

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ph.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ph.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ph.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ph.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ph.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ph.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Hoping for your immediate response with this concern.

Thank you.

Comment: Try a different mirror.

Answer (score 0):

This is now OK; I just put a DNS and restarted my network. After that, I can execute command `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install apache2` with out error encounter.